# Wordpress Loop - Not returning projects in specific category

Tags: loop

I am attempting to simply pull in all projects in a specific category (e.g. 'websites' or 'featured').

When using:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'project',
'category_name'  => 'websites',
'posts_per_page' => 10, 
);
```

Nothing is returned.

When using simply:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => 'project',
);
```

I do actually get posts (projects) returning, just not in the category I want.

Here is my full code:

```
function gmb_register_project_section () { 

$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'category_name'  => 'websites',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
);

$post_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($post_query->have_posts()) :
$output = '<div class="gmb_custom-project-module">';

    while ($post_query->have_posts()) {
        $post_query->the_post();

        $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink(). '"><article class="gmb_project-item" style="background: url(\''. get_the_post_thumbnail_url(). '\') no-repeat center center;"><div class="inner"><h2>'.
                get_the_title(). '</h2><div class="gmb_arrow-icon"><?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 512 512" style="enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;" xml:space="preserve"><g><g><path d="M506.134,241.843c-0.006-0.006-0.011-0.013-0.018-0.019l-104.504-104c-7.829-7.791-20.492-7.762-28.285,0.068 c-7.792,7.829-7.762,20.492,0.067,28.284L443.558,236H20c-11.046,0-20,8.954-20,20c0,11.046,8.954,20,20,20h423.557           l-70.162,69.824c-7.829,7.792-7.859,20.455-0.067,28.284c7.793,7.831,20.457,7.858,28.285,0.068l104.504-104 c0.006-0.006,0.011-0.013,0.018-0.019C513.968,262.339,513.943,249.635,506.134,241.843z"/></g></g></svg></div></div></article></a>';
    }

wp_reset_postdata();

$output .= '</div>';

endif;

return $output;

}
// Register shortcode
add_shortcode('gmb_project_section', 'gmb_register_project_section');
```

I am using the Divi theme, with a code module which allows you to input short codes into.

Thanks in advance, Ben

Answer (score 1):

You're sure that you have actual posts (`project` post type), that have that category selected on them, right?

Make sure the posts have an actual `category` selected, not a tag.  Also check in the categories configuration to make sure that `websites` is the actual slug of the category they are assigned to.

You can also try using the actual category id (find it while editing the category in admin area, in the URL bar), using this instead:
`'cat' => '1,2,3,4'`

or try
`'category__in' => 4`

I suspect the issue is probably with incorrect slug or some other configuration

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters

You can also try using a direct tax query:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => 'project',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'category',
            'terms'            => 'websites',
            'field'            => 'slug',
            'include_children' => true,
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes I have checked it is the correct post type, category name (slug) - I did even try using the category ID, and same outcome.. :/ (or rather, no outcome) - I'll give it another go though.

Comment: I am fairly new to wordpress development - could there be any conflicts from other similar functions? (e.g. I have another short code function which has `get_categories($args);` - however it each of these functions have `wp_reset_postdata();` towards the end.

Comment: Possibly, or something else could be filtering on it as well (plugin, theme, etc).  I updated the code with a direct tax query you can try

Comment: Just gave `tax_query` a go, still not working ahah! - It MUST be some other sort of conflict if the syntax is correct, hmmm.

Comment: The slug for the project category page is `project_category/websites` - is that normal?